# Is there another way to write this in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scope

I have this code:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :company_users do 
    def regular
      where('regular_user = ?', true)
    end

    def employee
      where('regular_user = ?', false)
    end
  end
```

and I want to know of another way to write this, or if this the most effecient way. I was thinking of a scope in the user model. Any ideas?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com would be a better place for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would write `regular` and `employee` as scopes of `User`:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :company_users 
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :regular, where(:regular_user => true)
  scope :employee, where(:regular_user => false)
end
```